# Como definir globalmente a saída de data padrão no Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, data

Eu me lembro bem quando eu usava o Laravel 4 que era possível converter globalmente os formatos de `created_at` e `updated_at`, para exibição em respostas JSON ou mesmo na chamada direta `{{ $model->created_at }}`.

Eu fazia da seguinte forma:

```
# app/global.php

Carbon\Carbon::setToStringFormat('d/m/Y H:i');
```

Assim, todas as vezes que eu chamava o método `Response::json` ou `Model::toJson()`, as datas eram convertidas para o formato supracitado.

Porém agora isso não tem acontecido. Geralmente, eu utilizo um método chamado `getCreatedAtBrAttribute` para obter as datas com a formatação. Também cheguei ao extremo de usar o `MomentJs` para converter essas datas pelo Javascript.

Mas agora quero uma solução no próprio Laravel.

Há alguma forma no Laravel 5 de fazer todas as datas terem um formato padrão, quando são chamadas como string?

Comment: Eu particularmente coloco no `$dates = ['data_inicio', 'data_fim'];` e depois adiciono no `$appends = ['data_format_br']`.

Comment: @DiegoSouza eu também faço isso, mas fica bem cansativo fazer isso em cada model: Eu tenho alguns sistemas com 44 models :p

Comment: E se colocar essa função de converter a data pra BR na classe que estende o Model ?

Comment: @DiegoSouza eu acho que é uma ótima solução. Vi algo parecido [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635427/laravel-5-global-date-accessor)

Comment: Talvez isto ajude Wallace: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sobreescreva o método [`serializeDate()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L754) agregado pelo trait [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php) em seus models.

Você pode fazer isso estendendo seus models de uma classe abstrata `AbstractModel` que estenda a classe [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php) ou ainda seguindo a prática do próprio Laravel de oferecer isso num trait próprio (como por exemplo `SerializesDateAttributes`) e usar ele nos models onde for necessário.

Comment: Rapaz, foi lá nas entranhas do framework! Great!

Answer (score 1):

você pode definir um mutator também (desde que esteja usando os tipos Date ou DateTime):

```
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d h:i:s',
];
```

Dê uma olhada nesse [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators), não sei qual a versão do laravel 5 você está usando, mas a partir da 5.6 isso já está disponível

Comment: Opa, obrigado pela informação. Bom saber que em novas versões esse problema já está resolvido de forma melhor